# Categorical_crossentropy loss function has value of 0.0000e +00 for a BiLSTM sentiment analysis model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp

This is the graph of my model

#### Model

[image]

Code format:

```py
def model_creation(vocab_size, embedding_dim, embedding_matrix,
                   rnn_units, batch_size,
                   train_embed=False):
    model = Sequential(
        [
            Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,
                      weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=train_embed, mask_zero=True),
            Bidirectional(LSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5)),
            Bidirectional(LSTM(rnn_units, dropout=0.25)),
            Dense(1, activation="softmax")
        ])


         return model
```

- The embedding layer receive an embedding matrix with value from Word2Vec
  This is the code for the embedding matrix:

#### Embedding Matrix

```py
def create_embedding_matrix(encoder,dict_w2v):
    embedding_dim = 50
    embedding_matrix = np.zeros((encoder.vocab_size, embedding_dim))

    for word in encoder.tokens:
        embedding_vector =  dict_w2v.get(word)

        if embedding_vector is not None: # dictionary contains word
            test = encoder.encode(word)
            token_id = encoder.encode(word)[0]
            embedding_matrix[token_id] = embedding_vector

    return embedding_matrix
```

#### Dataset

I'm using the amazon product dataset https://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/
This is what the dataframe look like

[image]

I'm only interested in overall and reviewText

- overall is my Label and reviewText is my Feature
- overall has a range of [1,5]

[image]

#### Problem

During training with categorical_crossentropy loss the is at 0.0000e +00, I don't think loss can be minimized well so accuracy is always at 0.1172

[image]

Did I configure my model wrong or is there any problem? How do I fix my loss function issue ? Please tell me if it's not clear enough I'll provide more information. I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: Output layer with 1 neuron and has softmax does not make sense, essentially you are throwing away what you learn and just output `1` everytime. The units should be equivalent to number of unique classes.

Comment: I agree, you should use as many output neurons as you have classes. What you are doing is a setting you would use for binary classification together with binary crossentropy loss.